# how convert ILIST<string> to ILIST <object> at C#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert `ILIST<string> to ILIST <object>`

How can achieve this using C#?

Answer (score 4):

```
var oList = (IList<object>)sList.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<string> s = new List<string>() ;
    IList<object> o = new List<object>();
    foreach (string x in o)
        s.Add(x);
```

Comment: Since you know the size in advance, you should create the new list by specifying its initial size, to avoid resizing: `new List<object>(s.Count)`. Another way is to use the constructor `public List(
 IEnumerable<T> collection
)` like this: `new List<object>(s.Cast<object>())`

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it:

```
IList<String> strings = new List<String> { "a", "b", };
IList<Object> objects = strings.Cast<Object>().ToList();
```

You can test the results in [LinqPad](http://linqpad.net) by calling: `objects.Dump();`

Answer (score 0):

```
stringList.Select(x => (object)x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

that is what the [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) are for.
you can use a simple Lambda expression for the conversion. Provided you are on .NET 2.0 or above.
eg:

```
 stringList.Select(x => (object)x).ToList();
```